# Magento HTTPS on all website: urls redirect to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, ssl

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and I have a problem with SSL.

I would like to have https on all the website, all pages. The site is hosted on a subfolder /shop/.

When I set base url (unsecure) on https version it works but I have one problem: when I visit an url with http it doesn't redirect to https version of that page but simple redirects to https version of the shop homepage.

So for example:

http://www.site.ext/shop/category/ redirect to https://www.site.ext/shop/

Can you help me?

This is the htaccess on /shop/:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /shop/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Please update your question with your htaccess (in `shop` subfolder)

Comment: I attached the code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any rule in your htaccess related to your https redirect. From where does it come from ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this after `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Works! Can you tell me how to make it working also for the primary shop section? Because internal pages redirects to https version but http://www.site.ext/shop/ doesn't redirect to https://www.site.ext/shop/

Comment: try adding the above code above `RewriteBase /shop/` instead of after the `RewriteRule` specified above.

Comment: For me it is not working, and a redirect loop is started. Can you please advice?

Comment: I also get a redirect loop. Anyone know what the corresponding url config in magento should be?

Comment: Try setting "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to No.

Answer (score 0):

One another thing that you need to remember is if you're site is accessed on https like

https://www.yourdomain.com/

> You should also make sure that the base Link URL should be on https
>   too. Otherwise Magento .htaccess rules will redirect you back to the
>   Base Url

So the bottom line is  **URL Base Link** under system - configuration - web - HTTP should be https://www.yourdomain.com/

After this clean / refresh your cache and reload your pages, This time magento wont reidrect you to home page.

> web/unsecure/base_link_url